# Angularjs4 with express generator

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Just developed a simple angular 4 application  with this tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

But how can i integrate angular 4 app to a express application that generated with express generator??.

One approach is REST API's method that is express JS app use as API provider and the angular application communicate with REST api.

But i would like to serve the angular application from express application itself..

Answer (score 2):

I think this will helpful to you. First I assume, you use express server to handle some api request and let's say those routes are begin with `/api`. they can be differ from yours.

- First build your angular application by `ng build` and it will create a folder called `/dist` in your project folder.
- Copy that folder in to your express project `/public` folder. You have to put them in an static routed folder. `/public` folder is a default static route folder. That is why I put it there. If you have your own one, you can put there too.
- edit your `app.js` file as follows

```
    // Set our api routes
    app.use('/api', api); // API router definitions.

    // Catch all other routes and return the index file
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    });
```

Hope you will help this way.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve it through your server like this:

```
// Catch root route and return index.html
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.html'));
});

// Catch all other routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app', req.originalUrl));
});
```

But be careful to set the right path to your `index.html`.

Comment: provide an explanation

Answer (score 0):

There is a technology stack called MEAN which means (coincidence :) **M**ongoDB, **E**xpress, **A**ngular and **N**odejs. So this is basically what you are looking for.

Altough you can create you own file structure, there is a mean-cli similar to Express-generator and the angular-cli. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mean-cli).

In order for Angular to work properly (like requesting a site like `example.com/something` and then also activate the route `something`) I always return my `index.html` for any request and setup express to return all static files as well. Then I create a route `/api` which handles all my REST api requests.

Make sure to first setup your `/api` route, then your other static files from angular like `bundle.js` and finally `index.html` as route `**`.